# Concatenate array if is not undefined

Tags: typescript

I´m concatenate two different arrays into one,

```
let myarray = [...myarray1, ...myarray2];
```

If myarray2 is undefined how can I make this concatenation in the best way?

```
 if(myarray2){
         let myarray = [...myarray1, ...myarray2];
    }
```

This is too ugly INMHO. Could i not do something like:

```
let myarray = [...myarray1, ...?myarray2];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may use this syntax

```
let myarray = [...(myarray1 ?? []), ...(myarray2 ?? [])];
```